# On close of modal getting blue colored border around the anchor tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this issue on close of a modal.

I found out that it was a bug and the solution lot of people used was

```
 .modal{
 outline:none!important
}
```

But for some reason, It isn't working for me.
Any solution for this?

Comment: it can have multiple reasons. for instance, the chrome browser has some outlining. also, the outline can occur on :focus and :active events, so add css for these aswell

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give that for `<a>`:

```
a, a:focus, a:active {outline: none !important; box-shadow: none !important;}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a ton. :))